# Referencing system views in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, system-tables

I've imported a database into SSDT containing a reference to a system view (specifically, sys.columns). The problem is, that I then get warnings about unresolved references when I build the project

From what I've seen on MSDN forums, it looks like it may be a known issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/5a7026bd-0602-42e6-a639-d73bed903c26

Now, I know I can switch the warning off or ignore it, but does anyone know of an actual solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should be handled by adding a reference to the master database.

[image: Add database reference dialog]

Previously, we've had issues related to the relative path that's used to reference the master.dacpac ([as described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/b6f5584e-4533-4228-9c37-f01d9cda9832/)). If I remember correctly, we pulled a copy of the master.dacpac file into the local project and referenced it using the last option shown in the dialog above. This is not ideal however as you'll need to remember to update your copy of the reference periodically.

Will update if I can find the details of what was causing a problem with the referencing method.

Answer (score 3):

References to sys.tables or similar can be resolved by just referencing master system db as visible in the picture of Mark`s answer.

In case you want to go the other way and use a dacpac to reference the system dbs, you can find it like so:

[image]